# Best of Rockabilly

Tags: genre, rock, similar-artists

I'd like to know some of the best or better known artist of the Rockabilly scene. Not current artist. The classic from the 50s-60s.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome vlassis. Unfortunately what's best is very opinionated. If you can give us objective criteria for finding songs, we'd be much more helpful.

Comment: Please don't edit questions that won't be reopened: this triggers a reopen request.